# sorting search result by distance

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, sorting

I have db table which has location details like postal code, long/lat data, region, city etc..
I am using this data to display users location in my web application. Now I want to sort places searched by user according to distance, like nearest place first. How can I calculate distance between users current lcation and the places he has searched and then sorting the result as per distance.

Comment: There are example of method if you [search](http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.java.html) carefully in google to calculate distance.

Comment: @antyrat: Thanks for this nice motivational link. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i just have this function for calculate distance between two latitude,longitude, pleaes have a look if its helpful to you.

function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
    var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
    var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
    var theta = lon1-lon2
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist)
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
    if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
    return dist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed have the `longitude` and `latitude` data, you can calculate with those to sort your search results.

---

**Example data:**

- The user that is performing the search has (longitude/latitude): 51.993073 , 5.952852
- User 1 (longitude/latitude): 52.893073 , 5.952852
- User 2 (longitude/latitude): 60.993073 , 5.952852

---

You can clearly see that "User 1" is closer to the user performing the search than "User 2" (see longitude).

Note: You need a formula to calculate this, check `JDev`'s answer.